# Unable to compare a list against a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to get my code to update the value of mostComp everytime it detects a number with a larger amount of factors, but keep being met with an:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
def MostComposite(integers):
    #The item in sequence 'integers' of positive integers which has
    #the greatest number of distinct factors, returns None if the sequence is empty.
    mostComp = 0
    for i in integers:
        if (Factors(i)) > 0:
            mostComp += i
            if (Factors(i)) > mostComp:
                mostComp += i
    return mostComp
```

Comment: You're comparing `Factors(i)` which returns a list to `0` which is an integer.

Comment: you presumably want `len(Factors(i))`

Comment: I have since solved that issue, however the code is still not returning the item in integers that has the largest amount of dividing factors, if you don't mind, could you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to compare different object types.

If you want to compare the length use `len(Factors(i))`.
Your code should look like:

```
def MostComposite(integers):
    #The item in sequence 'integers' of positive integers which has
    #the greatest number of distinct factors, returns None if the sequence is empty.
    mostComp = 0
    for i in integers:
        if len(Factors(i)) > 0:
            mostComp += i
            if len(Factors(i)) > mostComp:
                mostComp += i
    return mostComp
```

Comment: Hi, I have since solved that issue, however the code is still not returning the item in integers that has the largest amount of dividing factors, if you don't mind, could you please point me in the right direction.